# Convergence in distribution and continuous CDF

Tags: probability, statistics, convergence-divergence

I have two question related with convergence in distribution.

1. Let $X_n$ be a sequence of real random variables and $X$ be a real random variable such that $F_X$ is continuous at every point in $\mathbb{R}$. Let us suppose that $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$, that is $\lim_{n}F_{X_{n}}(x) = F_{X}(x)$ for every real number $x$. I want to show that $\lim_{n}\mathbb{P}(X_{n} < x) = \mathbb{P}(X<x)$ for every real number $x$.

I think is intuitive, from the fact that $F_{X}$ is continous, thus $\mathbb{P}(X = x) = 0$, but I can't see how to use the fact that $X_{n}$ converges in distribution to $X$.

2. Consider the same hypothesis above and consider $\{x_{n}\}_{n}$ a sequence of real numbers converging to $x$. I want to prove that $\lim_{n} F_{X_{n}}(x_{n}) = F_{X}(x)$.

Again I think it is intuitive from the fact that $F_{X}$ is continous at every point, but in the limit. I can't see how to manage it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(X<x)=P(X \leq x)$ since $F_X$ is continuous at $x$. [More generally, $P(X<x)$ is the left-hand limit of $F_X$ at $x$]. Hence, $$P(X_n < x) \leq P(X_n \leq x) \to P(X\leq x)=P(X<x).$$ Hence, $\lim \sup P(X_n<x) \leq P(X<x)$.  On the other hand, $$P(X_n <x) \geq P(X_n \leq X-\epsilon)\to P(X \leq x-\epsilon)$$ and letting $\epsilon \to 0$ we get $$\lim \inf P(X_N <x) \geq P(X<x).$$
For the second question use the follwoing:
[Weak convergence implies uniform convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550327/weak-convergence-implies-uniform-convergence)